# Uploaded 'png' 'bmp' images not uploading properly like 'jpeg' 'gif' images using similar code

Tags: php, image, gd

My program works perfectly with jpeg and gif images using the following code. However, when I try to upload png and bmp file, the images do not upload properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
list($width,$height)=getimagesize($imagefile);

if($_FILES['image']['type']=="image/png"){$src=imagecreatefrompng($imagefile);$type="png";}             
if($_FILES['image']['type']=="image/gif"){$src=imagecreatefromgif($imagefile);$type="gif";} 
if($_FILES['image']['type']=="image/bmp"){$src=imagecreatefromwbmp($imagefile);$type="bmp";}
if($_FILES['image']['type']=="image/jpeg"){$src=imagecreatefromjpeg($imagefile);$type="jpeg";}

$orig_h=($height/$width)* $orig_w;          
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($orig_w,$orig_h);
imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$orig_w,$orig_h,$width,$height);
imagejpeg($tmp,$folder.$filename,100);


if($type=="png"){imagepng($tmp,$folder.$filename,100);}         
if($type=="gif"){imagegif($tmp,$folder.$filename,100);} 
if($type=="bmp"){imagewbmp($tmp,$folder.$filename,100);}
if($type=="jpeg"){imagejpeg($tmp,$folder.$filename,100);}

imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: Maybe, the problem is caused by calling `imagejpeg` function after `imagecopyresampled`. Why do you need to call it?

Comment: `var_dump($type);` before `if($type=="png"){ ... }` - I don't see where this variable is defined. And let us know what it output.

Comment: Honestly, I wanted to crop a picture with a jquery plugin, and I copied an example off of YouTube, I am unfamiliar with the imagejpeg function @user4035

Comment: Then remove the first `imagejpeg($tmp,$folder.$filename,100);` call. And put `var_dump` that I asked you. Please, show us it's output.

Comment: maybe is your imagepng function, remove and test the "100" from that function...